# jQueryMobile: Button action not getting called

Tags: jquery-mobile

The code below tries to implements a button action in jQueryMobile,but it is not working for me. Please let me know where I am wrong.Everything is written in a HTML file.
I am facing some problem in providing my code here. Here is what I am trying.
In standard HTML format, I am writing the below code between `script` tags

```
$('#theButton').click(function() {
   alert('The Button has been clicked,');

});
```

And in the `body` tag ---

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <input type="button" id="theButton" name="theButton" value="The Button">
</div>
```

**But the action is not getting called.**

Comment: any chance of any more code? Is jQuery Mobile working? Is the script fragment actually being run? How do we know there aren't errors stopping the event from being bound? Have you got console open so you can say there are no errors?

Comment: Dear @popnoodles : please refer below the answer

Comment: is that the code you have and does it still not work?

Comment: @popnoodles: The code works & i have accepted the answer(see the green checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Please try the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

    $(function() {
     $('#theButton').on('tap click',function(event, ui) {
        alert('The Button has been clicked');
     });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <input type="button" id="theButton" name="theButton" value="The Button">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear @naoki, i am trying a simple example for the button action but its not working.I think i am missing a very basic element.

Comment: @naoki- When i run the file in iPhone Simulator(Safari browser) the alert shows: file://(null). Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure why it happens on iPhone Simulator. Is your code same as above?

Comment: yupp!. instead og running it into the web browser, i am running in mobile safari. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: With jQ Mobile click should work but change `$('#theButton').click(function()` to `$('#theButton').on('tap click',function()` and see if that triggers on tap.